# System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style

Tags: wpf, silverlight, sharepoint, xaml

got an exception when i call a silverlight xap in sharepoint. Hope anybody can help me out this problem. Here the exception:

> Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Set Property
>   'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception. [Line: 84
>   Position: 335]   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object
>   component, Uri resourceLocator)    bei
>   Project.MainPage.InitializeComponent()    bei
>   Project.MainPage..ctor(String eldoradoUrl, String eldoradoUser)    bei
>   Project.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
>   bei MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex,
>   Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)    bei
>   MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr
>   unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex,
>   String eventName)

And here is the xaml code line where the error supposed:

```
<fseld:EldoradoDocCreationView x:Name="ProtoEldoradoDocCreationView" Grid.Row="0"
   MaxColumnCount="2" FieldMargins="34 5 5 5" 
   RestrictToProperties="ProcedureName, FileItemText"
   CurrentItem="{Binding ProtoEldoradoDoc}" CommandButtonsVisibility="None"
   Margin="25,18,47,0" FontSize="10" Height="69" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Thanks for your replies in advance !

Comment: The XAML you posted contains no reference to any styles, although your error is with a Style. Can you post some more of your XAML?

Comment: And there are lots of custom properties that you don't explain. FieldMargins, RestrictToProperties? What are these?

Answer (score 0):

Does your Silverlight XAP work outside of Sharepoint? If no first correct the error outside, you will easier isolate the problem and may get more detailed exception information.

If it does work without Sharepoint then rather look at external assemblies that could contain styles that are not found in this context.